# Silverlight 4 custom control child items style

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have custom control where i want to show some items.
In generic.xaml defined style for custom control:

```
  <Style TargetType="local:Custom">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Customl">
                <!-- Root Grid-->
                <Grid x:Name="CustomLayout"
                      Background="Black">
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i set to C#

```
  [TemplatePart(Name = "CustomLayout", Type = typeof(Grid))]
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ChildItemStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(Control))]
public class GaugeControl : Control
```

Everything working fine excepts style for child items
defined in 
generic.xaml:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <!-- Root Grid-->
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                      Background="Red">
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Custom control with attribute

```
 [StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ChildItemStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(Control))]
```

And i have ChildItemStyle DependencyProperty in my custom control but its always null.

How can i get this Style property and whats wrong i am doing?

Comment: You use silverlight, right? Have you tried TargetType="Control" instead of x:Type...?

Comment: Yes i tryed but bug was that i had separet styles in generic.xaml insted of set one style for local:Custom with setter to set style to ChildItemStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and bug in my code.

I just add setter to my `<Style TargetType="local:Custom">` definition and with help of setter set ChildItemStyle which i want.